# Retrofit "form-urlencoded" request with @Field-annotated parameter

Tags: android, retrofit2, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have two queries:

```
@POST("/auth/login")
suspend fun login(@Body user: LoginUserDto): AuthResponse<TokenDto>

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/auth/refresh")
suspend fun refreshToken(@Field("refreshtoken") refreshToken: String): AuthResponse<TokenDto>
```

The first one is working well which means baseUrl is OK.
The second one returns `HTTP 404 Not Found`. WHen I look at Chucker interceptor logs, the url is correct and the refreshToken is present in the request. When I try to trigger it manually from `request.rest` in vsCode like this:

```
POST http://localhost:4000/auth/refresh/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5...blablabla
```

... it works fine.

The code of the endpoint starts like this (node.js server):

```
app.post('/auth/refresh/:refreshtoken', async (req, res) => {
    const refreshToken = req.params.refreshtoken;
    // some code
```

I believe I made mistake in my retrofit call `refreshToken(@Field("refreshtoken") refreshToken: String)`.
Could smb help how make such `@FormUrlEncoded` request with retrofit properly?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

@Field is used to send @FormUrlEncoded request in Retrofit which hides your parameter and not attach with url to provide security.Used for POST request.

@Query parameter appended to the URL.

If you are using @Field request than it will hides your parameter and not append with the url.

If you are using @Query request than all your parameter is append to your request and visible to users.

Depend on your api request you have to use one of above annotation. If the api request accept the @FormUrlEncoded data than use @Field or if they want to attached it with url than use @Query.